# Cannot find Python error "ImportError: No module"

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I do not know what I did wrong, but here is the code I have been using.

```py
import random

num = random.randint( 1, 100)

print("ELCOME TO GUESS ME!")
print("I'm thinking of a number between 1 to 100")
print("If your guess is more than 10 away from my number, I'll tell you you're COLD")
print("If your guess is within 10 of my number, I'll tell you you're WARM")
print("If your guess is farther than your most recent guess, I'll say you're getting COLDEER")
print("If your guess is closer than your most recent guess, I'll say you're getting WARMER")
print("LET'S PLAY!")

guesses = [0]

while True:

    guess = int(input("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100.\n  What is your guess? "))

    if guess < 1 or guess > 100:
        print('OUT OF BOUNDS! Please try again:')
        continue

    break

while True:

    # we can copy the code from above to take an input
    guess = int(input("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100.\n  What is your guess? "))

    if guess < 1 or guess > 100:
        print('OUT OF BOUNDS! Please try again: ')
        continue

    #here e compare the player's guess to our number
    if guess == num:
        print(f'CONGRATULATIONS, YOU GUESSED IT IN ONLY {len(guesses)} GUESSES!!')
        break

    # if guess is incorrect, add guess to our number
    guesses.append(guess)

    # when testing the first guess, guesses[-2]==0, which evaluates to False
    #and brings us down to the second section 

    if guesses[-2]:
        if abs(num-guess) < abs(num-guesses[-2]):
            print('WARMER!')
        else:
            print('COLDER!')

    else:
        if abs(num-guess) <= 10:
            print('WARM!')
        else:
            print('COLD!')
```

I keep getting an error when trying to run my code:

```
If your guess is closer than your most recent guess, I'll say you're getting WARMER
LET'S PLAY!
I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100.
  What is your guess? & C:/Users/Samarth/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.11.exe c:/Users/Samarth/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.12.0/pythonFiles/vscode_pytest/example.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Samarth\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.12.0\pythonFiles\vscode_pytest\example.py", line 17, in <module>
    guess = int(input("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100.\n  What is your guess? "))
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '& C:/Users/Samarth/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.11.exe c:/Users/Samarth/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.12.0/pythonFiles/vscode_pytest/example.py'
PS C:\Users\Samarth>
```

Comment: The error in your title and question disagree.

Comment: Why are you trying to input something which cannot be converted to an `int`? Did you want to catch such errors and retry the input?

Comment: Going by the error in the question body, what integer do you think `& C:/Users/Samarth/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.11.exe c:/Users/Samarth/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.12.0/pythonFiles/vscode_pytest/example.py` should be interpreted as? That's the string `input` is reading from stdin

Comment: @Brian61354270 - Isn't it more a question of why that string is there?

Comment: The result of your call to `input(..)` was that strange string. How did you run this program? Did you enter a number after the prompt? Any chance you accidentally pasted data? If you run this program multiple times, do you still get the same odd string?

Comment: Are you clicking the Run button in VSCode while your code is already running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm adding to Moses McCabe's answer. Consider the following line in your code:

```
guess = int(input("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100.\n  What is your guess? "))
```

If the conversion from a string to an integer fails, Python will throw a `ValueError`. Errors can be caught and handled using a try/except construct with the following syntax:

```
try:
  # Code that may fail
except:
  # Do something if the previous code failed
```

With this in mind, let's improve your code by checking if the input is valid and handling eventual errors:

```
try:
    # Try to get the user inpiut as an integer
    guess = int(input("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100.\n  What is your guess? "))
except ValueError:
    # If the string to integer conversion failed, print an error message and continue to the next iteration of the while loop
    print('Please enter a valid number.')
    continue
```

Also, you should completely remove the first while loop in your code. I don't know why it's there, maybe you forgot to delete it? The final code would look like this:

```
import random

num = random.randint( 1, 100)

print("WELCOME TO GUESS ME!")
print("I'm thinking of a number between 1 to 100")
print("If your guess is more than 10 away from my number, I'll tell you you're COLD")
print("If your guess is within 10 of my number, I'll tell you you're WARM")
print("If your guess is farther than your most recent guess, I'll say you're getting COLDEER")
print("If your guess is closer than your most recent guess, I'll say you're getting WARMER")
print("LET'S PLAY!")

guesses = [0]

while True:

    # we can copy the code from above to take an input
    try:
        # Try to get the user inpiut as an integer
        guess = int(input("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100.\n  What is your guess? "))
    except ValueError:
        # If the string to integer conversion failed, print an error message and continue to the next iteration of the while loop
        print('Please enter a valid number.')
        continue

    if guess < 1 or guess > 100:
        print('OUT OF BOUNDS! Please try again: ')
        continue

    #here e compare the player's guess to our number
    if guess == num:
        print(f'CONGRATULATIONS, YOU GUESSED IT IN ONLY {len(guesses)} GUESSES!!')
        break

    # if guess is incorrect, add guess to our number
    guesses.append(guess)

    # when testing the first guess, guesses[-2]==0, which evaluates to False
    #and brings us down to the second section 

    if guesses[-2]:
        if abs(num-guess) < abs(num-guesses[-2]):
            print('WARMER!')
        else:
            print('COLDER!')

    else:
        if abs(num-guess) <= 10:
            print('WARM!')
        else:
            print('COLD!')
```

Hope this solves your doubts. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Your code work perfectly. I ran it few time using PyCharm.

You're receiving **ValueError** because the string input is being converted to int. what'll happen if the user enter a letter or a character?

A **ValueError** is a type of **exception** that is raised when a function or operation receives an argument with the correct data type but an inappropriate value. It occurs when the input value is not within the expected range or doesn't fit the constraints defined by the function or operation.

If you try to convert a **string** to an **integer** using the **int()** function, and the string does not represent a valid integer, a **ValueError** will be raised.

for example:

```
# Trying to convert a non-integer string (letter, characters) to an integer
guess = int(input("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100.\n  What is your guess? ")) 
# user input: & or A etc...
```

This will result in a **ValueError**

Comment: As I'm new to this, can you tell me how to correct it?

Comment: @SS Please enter the int value you requested in your codes instead of other types. You can also try adding code to catch exceptions and handle them.

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT the specific string `& C:/Users/Samarth/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.11.exe c:/Users/Samarth/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.12.0/pythonFiles/vscode_pytest/example.py` looks like the command that would have been issued by VSCode to run the script. Is this something that would happen if the user clicks the "Run" button while the script is already running?

Comment: hey S S, I understand you're new to python. try to solve this problem using what you already know, such at condition statements or loop (while or if). for example: let assume you have two variables:
 a = 1 
 b = '2'
 to check if these two variable are of the same datatype. In python we use "type()". 
 if type(a) == type(int(b)): do something else: do something